# Access Sharepoint Library through Microsoft Access

Tags: sharepoint, ms-access, sharepoint-2010, ms-access-2010, sharepoint-list

Hi I have a sharepoint Library which is an **Infopath forms library**

I store forms here and i display some columns and the some column values are modified using MS Access

Now the problem that I am having is,

**Access Displays some records only where WEb browser displays all the records.**

I checked the security but everything looks correct for the same user has full control to that document

**Can someone say where I'm going wrong??**

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of linked list vs the Import the data source. 
The linked list will hide some fields due to how linking works.

[image]

There are some issues in this regard as well. Some Datatypes don't communicate well.
see;

- http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/how-access-converts-between-access-and-sharepoint-data-types-HP001047713.aspx
- http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/Sharepoint-Linked-Access-t1958466.html