# What is the best way to work with Access and SharePoint?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm a contractor currently working with the DOD. I work primarily with VBA and Microsoft Office (2013) to produce "Desktop Tools" because this is the level of scope in the culture here.  Rarely are the clients accessing their products from a fully integrated system that connects all of their data. One reason for this are the many disparate systems that require username and password to get and collect data.  So office products like MS Access, Excel and PowerPoint are the meat and potatoes of their reporting and dashboards.  There has been a second life to a career using only VBA which I thought was long gone.  My facility uses SharePoint 2010 and often want to see their products, like a "Desktop Access database with user security implemented" - on SharePoint. We often turn to PowerPoint to meet that need, but it is not as robust and requires a lot of manual intervention, and since many of the front end interfaces that I have built have complex form validation as well as comprehensive report views it seems to leave a lot to be considered.

I've only worked with Visual Studio between 2005 - 2009 and I know a lot has changed.  I know SharePoint has also evolved extensively.

I have also heard about InfoPath, but read that I need Visual Studio if I want true control especially with data input. I have also considered the Web App component in MS Access but have many security limitations on that side that I have never considered going through with them.  What are my options with SharePoint 2010 and Desktop MS Access that have all the bells and whistles available to me in VBA if I don't have access to Visual Studio or anything else besides VBA?

Comment: Visual Studio is completely out of the question?  You can make some very nice Access like applications that can work seamlessly with SharePoint using some relatively simple code these days.  There are OData and VBA methodologies for working with SharePoint in Access, but there are limitations and problems to that approach.  This is a good place to start if that's all you can do tho:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399050/access-sharepoint-library-through-microsoft-access?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1) You can create a database with Microsoft Access and publish it to Microsoft SharePoint 2010 using the [Access Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff402351(v=office.14).aspx)

2) You can create Sharepoint Lists and link them in Microsoft Access and work with them like tables and use VBA inside Microsoft Access